# Access child component data from parent component

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have a list in the child component. I want to access this list from the parent component (`AppComponent`) and display it using `@ViewChild` decorator, but the list is always undefined in the parent component

```js
export class CategorieComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() listCategories: Categorie[];

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        this.http.get<Categorie[]>('api/Categorie').subscribe(value => {
            this.listCategories = value;
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
}
```

app-component.ts

```js
@ViewChild(CategorieComponent, { static: false })
private categoryComponent: CategorieComponent;
.
.
.
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.listCategories = this.categoryComponent.listCategories;
}
```

app.component.html

```html
<option *ngFor="let cat of listCategories" [value]="cat.idCat" [selected]="cat.idCat == projet.idCat">
    {{cat.nomCat}}
</option>
```

Comment: Are you using `CategorieComponent` in parent component?

Comment: Also why you are not using service for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, I am. The parent component is actually `AppComponent`. And I am sure that the get call returns the list I need

Comment: I think to get data you should use service, not component.

Comment: Is it necessary to use component?

Comment: I'd like to separate the two components

Comment: thats fine, but why do you need service logic in controller. Can you post bit more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're trying to do here. But since there's an AJAX call required in the `CategorieComponent` and you want to get informed about the data retrieval success in the `AppComponent`, it kinda makes sense to expose the `listCategories` property as an `@Output` property.

But you'll then have to declare it as of type `EventEmitter<Array<Categorie>>`. Something like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

import { Categorie } from "../categorie.model";

@Component({
  selector: "app-categorie",
  templateUrl: "./categorie.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./categorie.component.css"]
})
export class CategorieComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output() listCategories: EventEmitter<Categorie[]> = new EventEmitter<Categorie[]>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get<Categorie[]>("/assets/categorie.json").subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
      this.listCategories.emit(value);
    });
  }
}
```

And in the `AppComponent` I'm not quite sure why you're using `ViewChild`. You'll simply have to call a method that handles the `listCategories` `@Output` event. Something like this:

```
<app-categorie 
  (listCategories)="setListCategories($event)">
</app-categorie>

<select name="" id="" *ngIf="listCategories">
  <option 
    *ngFor="let cat of listCategories" 
    [value]="cat.idCat" 
    [selected]="cat.idCat == projet.idCat">
    {{cat.nomCat}}
  </option>
</select>
```

You can then define the `setListCategories` method like this:

```
listCategories: Array<Categorie>;
projet = { };

setListCategories(listCategories) {
  console.log('listCategories:: ', listCategories);
  this.listCategories = listCategories;
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Sample Working Code**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-update-parent-list-when-data-is-fetched-in-child?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: What if the app-categories is not a direct child of AppComponent? And the app-categories doesn't actually have a selector? How do you access data from that component into the AppComponent?